# Stainless steel sleeves to hold wire rope?

Tags: repair, roof, deck, fence, steel

My original idea for the fence was to use eyebolts and rivnuts to close the wire, similar to the drawing below:

[image]

But then I saw a Stainless steel sleeve like the one below. I know it's used to protect the wire:

[image]

So I'm thinking... is there such a thing as a stainless steel sleeve that can also be used to hold the wire so that it does not move?

That way I would eliminate the rivnuts, eyebolts, and the loops. And it would be just one *piece* of wire across several posts. Something like this.

In theory, it's one piece of wire that crosses all 3 posts, and this stainless steel sleeve would be holding the wire:

[image]

Comment: you would have to use knots, crimped terminators, or mechanical fasteners to keep the wire from sliding, not sure how that would look. actually, you could do it _inside_ the tube, depending on the flexibility of the cable: feed it though both holes, bend, fish out the end, crimp, remove slack. not sure if you have clearance, but that would work and look great.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing appears to be similar to standard sailboat wire or cable "rails" and as such a visit to a boatyard/marine supplier would probably inform your process. Rather than being clamped at each post, the wires are typically tensioned from end to end (so the end-points need to be sturdy/strong.) They will also have crimp-sleeve (or swage-sleeve) fittings in stainless, but those are typically just at the ends (in your illustration, it would appear that you intend for them to be crimped inside the posts, which is impractical.)